# FXCop - Referenced assembly could not be found

Tags: .net, fxcop

I'm trying to use Microsoft FXCop Version 1.36 on a compact edition application but when I analyze the project I get the following error.

> The following referenced assembly
>   could not be found. This assembly is
>   required for analysis and was
>   referenced by application.exe
>
> System.Windows.Forms, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac,
>   Retargetable=Yes

It allows me to browse to find the assembly but it won't let me select the one in the GAC.

This assembly is in the GAC and the application itself works fine. Do I need to do something special to get FX Cop to find it?

Update: I've tried setting "Search Global Assembly Cache for missing references" under project options

Comment: note I have this problem on any compact edition applications, even a brand new test one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message but with a different assembly. The assembly in question was located in some random folder on my hard disk rather than in my project (don't ask me why). I moved the assembly FxCop was complaining about into my project bin folder and it worked fine (again don't ask my why)

Answer (score 0):

Would it help if you pointed to the actual .NET CF assemblies, as directed in this [MSDN Forums Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxcompact/thread/0425fd0b-56e5-4711-bc09-ce5372976957)?